# gitolite permissions: what does the 'C', 'D' and 'M' options do?

Tags: git, gitolite

The [documentation](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/rules.html) wrongfully (in my mind) assumes that the reader should be familiar with all the possible permissions combinations:

> The full set of permissions, in regex syntax, is **`-|R|RW+?C?D?M?`**. This expands to one of **`-, R, RW, RW+, RWC, RW+C, RWD, RW+D, RWCD, or RW+CD`**, all but the first two optionally followed by an M. And **by now you know what they all mean**.

the problem is, All but the first 4 cases are *not* discussed in the document.

Can someone please explain what these additional 'C', 'D' and 'M' symbols mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More on [gitolite doc](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf-2#appendix-1-different-types-of-write-operations).

C allows you to push but not create a ref, D allows you to rewind but not delete a ref, and M allows you to reject merge commits.

> Sometimes you want to allow people to push, but not create a ref. Or
>   rewind, but not delete a ref. The C and D qualifiers help here.
>
> When a rule specifies RWC or RW+C, then rules that do NOT have the C
>   qualifier will no longer permit creating a ref.
>
> Please do not confuse this with the standalone C permission that
>   allows someone to create a repo
>
> When a rule specifies RWD or RW+D, then rules that do NOT have the D
>   qualifier will no longer permit deleting a ref.
>
> Note: These two can be combined, so you can have RWCD and RW+CD as
>   well.
>
> One very rare need is to reject merge commits (a commit series that is
>   not a straight line of commits). The M qualifier helps here:
>
> When a rule has M appended to the permissions, rules that do NOT have
>   it will reject a commit sequence that contains a merge commit (i.e.,
>   they only accept a straight line series of commits).

Comment: thanks, It appears I was linked to a limited version of the document :)